# Parse PFSubclassing in Swift of Object type

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm pretty new to iOS/Swift/Parse and I'm trying to build a model of a class using PFSubclassing.

**The data I'm trying to represent should look something like this**

```
{
    text: ""
    location : {
        name: "",
        longitude: "",
        latitude: ""
    }
}
```

**So fare the model I'm have is**

```
class LocationModel {
    var name: String?
    var longitude: Float?
    var latitude: Float?
}


class PostModel: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

    class func parseClassName() -> String! {
        return "Post"
    }

    @NSManaged var text: String?
    var location: LocationModel?
}
```

The `test` property is being saved successfully but I'm unable to get the `location` properties to save.

**The code I'm using to save a record to parse is**

```
var test = PostModel()
    test.location?.name = "ESB"
    test.location?.latitude = 1
    test.location?.longitude = 1

    test.text = "This is a test post to see if this works!"

test.saveEventually { (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    println(error)
    println(success)
}
```

I did a lot of digging online but I'm unable to find a solution on how to represent an `Object` datatype in Swift using Parse `PFSubclassing`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

I will create a Hero object for example.

```
class Hero: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

@NSManaged var strengthPoint: Double
@NSManaged var name: String

static func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "Hero"
}

init(strengthPoint: Double, name: String) {
    super.init()
    self.strengthPoint = strengthPoint
    self.name = name
}

init(pfObject: PFObject) {
    super.init()
    self.strengthPoint = pfObject.object(forKey: "strengthPoint") as! Double
    self.name = pfObject.object(forKey: "name") as! String

}

override init() {
    super.init()
}

override class func query() -> PFQuery<PFObject>? {
    let query = PFQuery(className: self.parseClassName())
    query.order(byDescending: "createdAt")
    query.cachePolicy = .networkOnly
    return query
}
}
```

Now, after defining your model, you can use these methods to store and retrieve

**Create your object in server**

```
func createHero() {
    let hero = Hero(strengthPoint: 2.5, name: "Superman")
    hero.saveInBackground { (isSuccessful, error) in
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Success")
    }
}
```

**Retrieve object from server**

```
func retrieveHero() {
    let query = Hero.query()
    query?.getFirstObjectInBackground(block: { (object, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Something's wrong here")
        } else if let object = object {
            let hero = Hero(pfObject: object)
            print(hero.strengthPoint) // 2.5
            print(hero.name)          // Superman
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen several different methods for `PFSubclassing` in Swift 1.2, but the following works best for me:

To begin with, make sure that you have the following in your Objective-C Bridging Header:

```
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>
```

Here is a very basic example of subclassing `PFObject`:

```
import Foundation
import Parse

class Car: PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    override class func initialize() {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }

    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Car"
    }

    @NSManaged var model: String
    @NSManaged var color: String
    @NSManaged var yearManufactured: Int

}
```

So in your case, this would be:

```
class PostModel: PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    override class func initialize() {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }

    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Post"
    }

    @NSManaged var text: String?
}
```

Concerning your `LocationModel`...I'm a bit confused as to what exactly you are trying to accomplish with that.  I hope this helps.